# How to effectively append paremeter to multiple, different grub config file using regex

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have multiple systems, some with no GRUB parameters and some with multiple parameters:

One system has this configuration:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

One system has this configuration:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0 net.ifnames=0 bios.devname=0 audit=1"
```

One system has this configuration:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 bios.devname=0 audit=1"
```

My goal is to append `ipv6.disable=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` on ALL of the systems, but I'm not sure how to using sed/awk/etc.

Comment: You are expected to make an effort. Also see [Strange and maddening rules](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/04/23/strange-and-maddening-rules/) and [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed  '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINU/ s/"$/ ipv6.disable=1"/g'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0 net.ifnames=0 bios.devname=0 audit=1 ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 bios.devname=0 audit=1 ipv6.disable=1"
```

Or

```
sed -r '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/ s/="|"$/&ipv6.disable=1 /;s/ "$/"/' 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1 console=tty0 console=ttyS0 net.ifnames=0 bios.devname=0 audit=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1 net.ifnames=0 bios.devname=0 audit=1"
```

here, if the line contains `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` then search line ending with `"` and replace it with `ipv6.disable=1`.